# Nonexistent property at PHP class

Tags: php, class, properties

PHP:

If you instantiate a class and then read or write a nonexistent property previously, is this property is added to the class object or all objects of the same?

Comment: Only to that instance; and reading a non-existent property won't add anything to the instance, only setting a property

Comment: _writing_ to a non-existing property will add that property as a new `public $<propertyName>` property. Non-static, meaning: only to that instance. But avoid doing that as much as you can. Predefined properties _are_ faster than messy ones, _and_ less error prone (think `$instance->name  = 123; echo $instance->nmae;` <== typo's are common)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: is there a way to ask PHP to throw error in this situation (trying to assign to a non-existent property)? Like VB.NET has an `Option Explicit`, which has a slightly different usage, but just quoting an example.

Comment: No idea, I've not written PHP in a good 3 years now

Answer (score 1):

1. Property will not be added if you are trying to read it.
2. New property will be added into current object only

Test script:

```
$o1 = new stdClass();
$o2 = new stdClass();
$a = $o1->property; // PHP Notice:  Undefined property

var_dump($o1); // class stdClass#1 (0) {}
var_dump($o2); // class stdClass#2 (0) {}

$o1->property = 'property';

var_dump($o1); // class stdClass#1 (0) {public $property => string(8) "property" }
var_dump($o2); // class stdClass#2 (0) {}

$o3 = new stdClass();
var_dump($o3); // class stdClass#3 (0) {}
```